# How to make a indy HTTPServer in console application

Tags: delphi, indy, httpserver

i'm trying to do a HttpServer with Delphi 7/indy(9) component (console application, without Forms/Application):

UPDATE: A Full console example with infinite loop.

```
program httpserver;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  IdHTTPServer, IdTCPServer, IdCustomHTTPServer;

Type
  TCommandHandler= class
  protected
    procedure DoCommandGet(AThread: TIdPeerThread;
      ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);

end;

{$R *.res}
var Server:TIdHTTPServer ;
CH:TCommandHandler;


procedure TCommandHandler.DoCommandGet(AThread: TIdPeerThread;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
   AResponseInfo.ResponseText := '1234';
end;

begin
  Server := TIdHTTPServer.Create(nil);
  CH := TCommandHandler.Create;
  Server.OnCommandGet :=CH.DoCommandGet;
  Server.DefaultPort := 3030;
  Server.Active := True;
  while true do ;
end.
```

but not works!i read the source code of indy and searched on google without success.

UPDATE:

1. Without loop, the program ends (of course...)
2. With loop, the response is very strange.(concatenation of status code - OK + response)
   http://www.image-share.com/upload/2766/294.png
3. With Form, the response is ok.
   http://www.image-share.com/upload/2766/295.png

perhaps a bug/limitation with indy...

Comment: It works fine. It's just that your application ends when it hits the `end;` (which is actually an `end.`, BTW - please post your real code when you're asking a question here). In order for your code to keep running, you need a loop that runs until you tell it to stop with an exit condition. (For future questions, "not works" is not a good problem description; you need to tell us exactly how it fails to work the way you expect.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are setting the wrong member in `AResponseInfo`. 
You must use `ContentText` instead of `ResponseText` (which will be written after the ResponseCode as you found out)

```
program httpserver;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  IdHTTPServer, IdTCPServer, IdCustomHTTPServer;

Type
  TCommandHandler= class
  protected
    procedure DoCommandGet(AThread: TIdPeerThread;
      ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);

end;

{$R *.res}
var Server:TIdHTTPServer ;
CH:TCommandHandler;


procedure TCommandHandler.DoCommandGet(AThread: TIdPeerThread;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := '1234';
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/plain';
end;

begin
  Server := TIdHTTPServer.Create(nil);
  CH := TCommandHandler.Create;
  Server.OnCommandGet :=CH.DoCommandGet;
  Server.DefaultPort := 3030;
  Server.Active := True;
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to do a endless loop, and watch to close with some combinations.

```
program  httpserver;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses idHTTPServer;


var 
  Server: TidHTTPServer;
begin
  Server := TidHTTPServer.Create();
  Server.DefaultPort := 3030;
  Server.Active := True;

  repeat
    //DO SOMETHING
  until (Break some how);
end;
```

So the app never ends, on delphi with the command application.run starts a internal loop for the windows messages.

Other matter, needs to add code for the events on the TidHTTPServer component